# Botón para volver a página anterior sin recibir mensaje "Confirmar reenvío del formulario" en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente formulario

```
<form class="form-inline float-right" method="post">
  <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control datepicker" name="fechainicial" id="fechainicial" value="<?php echo $finicial; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $finicial; ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control datepicker" name="fechafinal" id="fechafinal" value="<?php echo $ffinal; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $ffinal; ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Generar</button>
  </div>
    <?php if(isset($_POST['fechainicial']) && isset($_POST['fechafinal'])) { ?>
      <div class="form-group mb-2">
        <a href="excelreport.php?sp=PacientesMayorCompra&finicial=<?php echo $finicial; ?>&ffinal=<?php echo $ffinal; ?>"
        class="btn btn-success"
        style="background-color: #28a745;border-color: #28a745;">
        <i data-feather="download"></i> Excel
        </a>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</form>
```

lo que hace es generar una lista como la primera foto, y al darle clic al nombre que es un enlace me envía hacia la segunda foto lo que quiero es crear un botón que envíe de vuelta con la lista, y no salga lo de reenvió de formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Esto te sirve?  `<button onclick="history.back()">Volver</button>` o te relanza el reenvio de formulario?

Comment: Si me relanza el envio

Comment: Pues usa un enlace `<a href="url_anterior">Volver</a>` y mediante CSS haces que parezca un boton (o deja simplemente el enlace)

Comment: <button onclick="history.go(-2)"> Regresar 2 páginas </button> Regresa _dos_ páginas, hacia el formulario en el estado en que se encontraba antes de enviarlo

Answer (score 0):

Si no es condición indispensable que los datos del formulario vayan por POST, yo cambiaría el método del formulario a GET. Yo creo que así no te daría el problema del reenvío (he hecho una prueba rápida de formulario con POST y con GET, y al recargar página solo me ha saltado el aviso de relanzar con POST). Te aparecerán los parámetros en la URL, pero al ser fechas no es crítico que se vean y se pueden modificar fácilmente.

Luego ya en el botón de "Volver" pones la acción de `history.back()` y vuelve a la primera página con los parámetros pasados. Eso sí, no lo pongas directamente sobre el HTML porque es una [mala práctica](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these)

A ver si hay suerte